# Core Data with multiple similar entities or single large entity

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I want to store the text of 5-10 books using `Core Data`. Given each book can be quite long (think 30,000 lines), would I be better off:

1. Creating one Entity to contain all books with different book titles (ie. `NSString` `attributes` for bookTitle, lineNumber, lineText, etc) or,
2. Multiple Entities, one for each book (with the same attributes, ie. lineNumber, lineText)?

Seems like option 2 is cleaner, but just not sure if it'd be wise having multiple Entities, identical in schema, just with differing names (logically makes sense given books have different names)

Editing with code snippet below. Would I use predicates if I want to filter to just search in one book entity?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:version
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard model for this type of thing is to create an `NSManagedObject` called **Book** for example and have that entity have the various properties of a book, e.g. title, author, text, etc.

```
@interface Book : NSManagedObject {}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *author;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;
...
```

It could obviously get more complicated than this if for example you wanted to break text into blocks of chapters etc. It really depends on what your overall design goals are.

Comment: That makes sense, but in my Data Model, doesn't that means I only have one entity now with those properties? So say whenever I need to display a book's text content, won't I also be loading all the data for the other books given they all sit under one entity now?

Comment: An NSManagedObject IS a single entity which is sort of analogous to a database record. So the row is called **Book** with the columns being title, author, etc. Your core data database will contain multiple instances of that entity.. if you load one book, you are loading one entity.

Comment: My biggest concern is organizing this properly for fast lookup. Ie, if I want to quickly search through the db to pull out say line 5 of book 7, I want my structure to be set in the most efficient manner. Given my `NSFetchRequest` is based off of the entity I provide it, I'm just concerned that if I group everything into one Entity and later subclass it to a single `NSManagedObject` - my single db will be too large for quick lookup

Comment: You are still not getting it... and you are worrying about optimization before you understand what CoreData is. As I've said about three different ways now: an NSManagedObject IS A SINGLE ENTITY. It is basically the model of your entity. All the properties define the entities attributes. Your database will contain one instance of the Book entity for each book in the database. If you are searching for text in a single book, you will do that in a single book entity.

Comment: And since you are @SimplyLearning, it is customary to mark answers correct or at least give them an upvote, when you ask essentially general help me learn questions :) It will improve your Reputation, and make it more likely that people will answer your questions in future.

Comment: My apologies, definitely still in the learning phases here. What I'm not quite following here is when you say "the row is called Book." I thought the complete db was the Book entity (entity = table), hence when you are returned the array when calling `managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest`, you are returned all the rows. Is my understanding truly incorrect? Will edit post with code snippet, but if I want just a specific book instead of all books, am I correct to say I need to use predicates on my fetchRequest? Else I don't see how I can limit to just the rows relevant to one book.

Comment: Sure. A CoreData DB contains a bunch of entities. If you define a Book entity, it will contain One book entity for each Book in the database. So if you add 5 books then it will contain 5 book entities. To access one book, you will execute a fetchRequest on the database with some kind of selector that specifies which book entity you want... eg title. When it finds a book entity with a matching title it will fetch the entire entity or book and then you can sort around in the books text field for whatever you are looking for in that book.

Comment: Ty! Makes a ton more sense. So..if I'm not mistaken then, what I've actually been doing without having a clue is that every time I'm creating a new obj for my entity (`NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:version inManagedObjectContext:context]`) inside a for loop (iterating over a csv file - each line of the book is a new row), I'm actually saving thousands of the same book Entities (with each entity only storing 1 line of text). This def doesn't sound correct..will look into more, but as a final ask, would you mind sending me in the right direction to do this the correct way?

Comment: @Simply, the performance is not going to be materially faster or slower depending on which of the two ways you have described is used.  By using the entity as described in the answer above and moving it to a separate external file, Core Data will fetch the text of the book only when it is actually needed.  It will also perform caching as required.  Whether it is one entity or ten isn't going to make any difference.

You are not dealing with a traditional relational database system and unless you have a lot of very large objects this seems unlikely to be a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could store it in a single entity and tell Core Data to put the text field an a separate "external" record file if the performance suffers.

Answer (score 1):

Better approach will be to create 2 entities, One having the metaData of Book and 2nd one having actual text. Both the Entities is mapped using a one-one relationship and we can create the appropriate delete rules. advantage of this approach will be when you are loading list of books say in UITableView/UICollectionView you can display the Title/author details and that metadata will much lighter. When user clicks on a particular book(title/author), we can fetch the text using the mapping and can show it using a viewController. When we create mapping we already getting methods to add/remove items from relationship entities

Below is the implementation of the same:

```
@interface Book : NSManagedObject {}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *author;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *genre;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *publication;
....



@interface Bookdata : NSManagedObject {}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Text;
```

Comment: I do like this approach when it comes to listing out all the book titles, but is it still worth it if my metaData is quite limited, consisting say only the title and author? Also won't this mean, if anytime I need to pick out just one line from a book, I'll need to create two NSManagedObjects as opposed to one? If I know the number of books will be limited, couldn't I technically just hardcode it in my UITableView?

Comment: I opted out for 2 entities as your text of book can be of any lenght ranging it from few bytes to MB's. So loading everything at once will be a perfromance hit for the application. Also when designing your application consider a broader wision or future enhancement like what if metadata increases, loading books from a server etc.... In that case your architecture of application plays a major role.